# Some replace methods are ignored

Tags: java, file, loops, for-loop

I have multiple replace methods (I mean around 200 replace commands all nested in for loops). But some replace methods don't work at all. I am looping through the file using a For loop:

```
for(i=0; i<file.length; i++) {
```

but some replace methods are being ignored. Is there a reason why some methods are being ignored and some aren't?

EDIT1:
I'm trying to replace multiple strings in a file.

```
file[i].replace(str1, str2)
file[i].replace(str3, str4)
file[i].replace(str5, str6)
file[i].replace(str7, str8)
file[i].replace(str9, str10)
...
and so on...
```

Here's the code:

Click [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?zaplybx617af75x)!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace? We need a little more code in order to help you.

Comment: Yes, you have a bug in your code. *Again* we can't guess what it is based on the limited information you've provided. *Again* if you need better help, you need to ask a better question.  **Again** please read the links I've given you on how to ask better questions.

Comment: @Hovercraft, I am just using a for loop and then MANY MANY replace commands. That's all! What's so hard to understand?

Comment: @rudna, consider it from our perspective: we have no idea how the array `file` is initialized. We have no idea why you're working on an entire array of filenames or file contents rather than one at a time. We have no idea how `str1` and `str2` are initialized. We're not sitting there with you :) and we can't debug anything with what we can see here.

Comment: @rudna: you've got to be kidding. Yes you've got many replace "commands" but since some are not being run, they have bugs. Again, there's no way for us to magically be able to tell you what is going wrong based on what you're telling us. Please remember, we can't read minds.

Comment: @rudna1010, I would suggest putting more effort into your questions. There is way too much of guesswork involved, both in determining what you are attempting to say, and also in the problem that you are facing. I would suggest that you put more effort in being clear about the problem you are facing. For example, which one of your replace method invocations are facing? Additionally, if you have attempted debugging your code, what part of it's behavior have you failed to understand. Putting that down in your question will help.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate this. "str1" and "str2" are just normal strings. Like files[i].replace("hello", "goodbye"); ALSO file[i] is just an array that reads the file. It's initialized correctly. Some files can replace strings, some cannot.

Comment: @vineet: check out his posting history. Every question of his we go through this same process of trying to extract information from him like pulling teeth. Every time we tell him to study the links on how to ask questions here, and each time he ignores this advice. I'm wondering if he's a troll and doing this stuff on purpose or if he's simply not up to snuff.

Comment: ALL RIGHT guys, stay put, I'll give you the input, and you run it and see.

Comment: @rudna1010, of course they are normal strings. No one misunderstood that part. The point is about which replace statement failed and on what inputs.

Comment: @Hovercraft, I'm aware of that. All questions posed today have been ignored by me. I felt I had to jut in and be polite.

Comment: @Hovercraft - I think the latter.  If someone has no clue as to how to debug things (and maybe no clue about what Java code means) then it is all black magic.  It is a small step to assuming that the magicians are simply being lazy when they keep on asking for more information.

Comment: That useless link popped up a window displaying a bunch of advertizing plus a message saying "this offer is not available in your area".  This question deserves to be closed with extreme prejudice ...

Comment: @rudna1010, I did open those two files. What am I supposed to do with those? The first contains 400 lines in a for loop, and won't compile. The second is not even Java; it must be some input to your program. If so, why did you not bother posting the complete program? How can you be reasonably certain there is no bug lurking in the other lines of your code, especially if you haven't found out which line in those 400 have failed?

Answer (score 3):

As written, none of the `replace` statements are doing anything (assuming `file` is a `String[]`) because `String`s are immutable and `replace` returns a new `String` without modifying the original. You'd need to write:

```
file[i] = file[i].replace(str1, str2);
```

Comment: That's what I'm writing.

Comment: @rudna1010: Perhaps you should have written what you're writing in the question then, instead of something syntactically incorrect that doesn't do what you're doing at all.